# The API Version specified is not valid Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am facing the error for signing the docusign after opening the recipient Url in browser.
Below is the error.

INVALID_API_VERSIONThe API Version specified is not valid.

Can anyone provide me the solution.
I am also not getting email notification from docusign.

Thanks in advance,
Kirti

Answer (score 2):

Please provide the complete DS endpoint which you are using to generate Recipient URL, it seems you are using non-public version of API. Please check if you are using V2 version of API or not.

Comment: <errorDetails xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<errorCode>INVALID_API_VERSION</errorCode>
<message>The API Version specified is not valid.</message>
</errorDetails>

Comment: This is not the completed endpoint URL, it will be having some version number as well

Comment: This is what the complete URL is https://na3.docusign.net/Signing/StartInSession.aspx?t=27b2ca37-d932-46f9-9f6e-b4e0ed53e158

Comment: its created by  envelopesApi.createRecipientView() API call

Comment: let me correct .. its .. https://NA3.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/   Here i am using the V2 api version

Comment: So you are getting RecipientViewURL via API call? but on opening that URL on browser it is throwing INVALID_API_VERSION error? Can you please share the snapshot of the browser error, also please share your JSON request which you are passing to generate RecipientView URL.

Comment: RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = new RecipientViewRequest();

           
            viewRequest.setReturnUrl(BaseUrl + "/ds-return");

            viewRequest.setAuthenticationMethod("email");

            viewRequest.setEmail("abc@xcd.com");

            viewRequest.setUserName("abc");

            viewRequest.setClientUserId("abc@xcd.com");

            // call the CreateRecipientView API

            ViewUrl results1 = envelopesApi.createRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId, viewRequest);

Comment: Its better to update code in your initial qs by editing your qs. On another note, can you please capture API logs from DocuSign directly so that we can see whats hitting DS platform when you are getting API_VERSION Error. Please capture the logs by following the steps as explained [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging), and you have to enable logs for the user which you are using in your code for API calls.